# Passing the selected Radio button value to Controller C# MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, radio-button

I have a table that display the Customer ID, Customer Name and a radio button looping. I am trying to link the user logged in based on the option given on my table.

> Email: test@gmail.com
>
> CustID | CustName | SelectUser
>
> 1234   | Test 1   | radiobutton (checked)
>
> 2345   | Test 2   | radiobutton

What I want is, if the radiobutton is checked(which is custId: 1234), I want to grab that CustID.

Here's my code:

Controller

```
public ActionResult AddCustomerLinkToDB(string IsSeleted)
{
   string selectedCustomer = IsSeleted;
   return View();
}
```

cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddCustomerLinkToDB", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th>Customer ID</th>
            <th>Customer Name</th>
            <th>Select this user</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Id</td>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
                <td>@Html.RadioButton("IsSelected", new { id = item.Id })</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

Comment: `IsSelected` is  not `IsSeleted`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hey Stephen, good catch, but unfortunately, it did not work. I am still getting null.

Comment: It will work fine assuming that method is `[HttpPost]`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I did double check that, and my method is [HttpPost]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than passing single `string` argument, you can try to create a viewmodel that stores both of selected value and radio button items. Here is example of proper viewmodel setup:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    // since the CustID is numeric, I prefer using 'int' property
    public int IsSelected { get; set; }

    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

The view page should be look like this, by using `RadioButtonFor` to bind with `IsSelected` property:

```
@model ViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddCustomerLinkToDB", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th>Customer ID</th>
            <th>Customer Name</th>
            <th>Select this user</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Customers)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Id</td>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
                <td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsSelected, item.Id, new { id = item.Id })</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

Finally, the controller parameter should be adjusted to accept viewmodel class like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddCustomerLinkToDB(ViewModel model)
{
    int selectedCustomer = model.IsSelected;
    // other stuff

    return View();
}
```

By using this setup, the selected value will be stored in `IsSelected` property during form submit.

Comment: Thank you for this, Tetsuya!

Comment: Hi Tetsuya, every time I am calling the RadioButtonFor, it is giving me an error "HtmlHelper<dynamic> does not contain a definition for 'RadioButtonFor' and the best extension method overload". Not sure regarding this